# How to transform a grammar into LL(1) grammar form?

Tags: context-free-grammar, automata

```
E -> E+E|E*E|(E)|a
```

Given the grammar,
how can I transform the grammar into LL(1) form?

```
E->aX|(E)
X->+E|*E|epsilon
```

Is this LL(1) grammar?

Answer (score 1):

The original grammar is left recursive, thus not LL(1), in fact not LL(k) for any k.

Fortunately left recursion can be removed. The standard algorithm does this by separately addressing immediate left recursion (as we have here) and indirect left recursion. Immediate left recursion is the simpler case of the two. The Wikipedia article explains it [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_immediate_left_recursion).

Basically you move the parts following the recursive reference into a new production (the tail), that also has an `ε` alternative,

```
   X -> ε|+E|*E
```

Then you remove left recursive alternatives from the original production, and allow `X` to follow all of the remaining non-recursive alternatives,

```
   E -> (E)X|aX
```

Note that your proposal misses `X` following the parenthesized expression, thus it does not recognize the same language.

Comment: FWIW: The original grammar is also ambiguous, and hence not LR(k) for any k either. The transformed grammar is not ambiguous, but its parse does not conform to normal arithmetic precedence. Probably both of those facts will be covered later in the course.

Answer (score -1):

) Find FIRST(S) and FOLLOW(S) for this grammar:
 S → d S a S
→ c S b S 
→ ε

Comment: Is this even related to the question?